# mongodb, finding by coordinate + query

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm building a web application over Node.js and MongoDB which is based on geolocated points.

The document is something like this:

```
{ name: ""
keywords: [Array of strings]
location: {lng: double, lat: double } 
}
```

I am wondering how could I use `find()` to find documents that are near from a coordinate but, in addition, are coincident with any of he keywords in the keywords array.

Imagine that keywords are: `["restaurant", "bar", "coffee"]`

I've looked into **2d Index**, but the secondary index must be a string. It can't be an array of strings.

The problem is that a document could have more than one keyword (or category) so I can't use a simple string to query them

How would you implement this?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi. Have you looked at $in yet for the keyword array? That should help with part of your issue. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/in/

Answer (score 0):

What version of mongo? It looks like this was added in 2.4.0: [SERVER-8457](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8457)